# Is there a way of pausing background music(such as spotify) then play a sound file, then play the background music again in an ios application?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way of pausing background music (such as Spotify) then play a sound file, then play the background music again in an ios application?

I've tried to use AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioSession. I tried this:

```
try  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers])
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I really appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 1):

You can play and pause Apple's music app songs with this code:

```
import MediaPlayer

let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.systemMusicPlayer

musicPlayer.playbackState == .paused || musicPlayer.playbackState == .stopped ? musicPlayer.play() : musicPlayer.stop()
```

So, you can sandwich the code that plays your audio file between 2 calls to the above code.

```
import MediaPlayer

let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.systemMusicPlayer

if (self.musicPlayer.playbackState == .playing) {
  musicPlayer.stop()
}

//Play your audio file

self.musicPlayer.play()
```

You might want to use this code to set a playing queue if no song was playing initially.

```
musicPlayer.setQueue(with: .songs())
```